# List newform display another list column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have question regarding newform and parent/child relationship between two lists.

I have a list incident and a column name issue list (dropdown). The Issue list dropdown has the name of other list.

Now in the Incident list Newform  when the user  select one of the Issue list name from the dropdown then the corresponding list field should be displayed in the incident list newform ?.

How can i achieve this ?.

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen when the user selects something from the dropdown?

Comment: When the user select the dropdown i want to display the corresponding list column in the newform. Actually i have achieved this using Infopath form using the Rules. Now i don't know how to join 2 list when the user save the list item ( the column value should be stored in corresponding list).